# How do I change my code so that it lists month name instead of only the month number

Tags: c

As the title says, I want my code to list the actual month name instead of listing only the month number.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int day, month, year;
  printf("Enter day, month and year : ");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &month, &year);
  if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
    printf("Wrong input data!");
 }
  else if (year < 1 || year > 4000) {
    printf("Wrong input data!");
 }
  else if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
    printf("Wrong input data!");
 }
  else {
    printf("The date entered is %d. %d %d. \n", day, month, year);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Oh and I have literally just started learning C programming so I only know how to use switch case and else/else if.

Edit: Thanks to everyone that suggested using arrays and writing the code, but as I said I still dont know how to use them. Welp everyone is still giving the same response, so this question is useless. Thanks anyways guys.

Comment: create an array of strings as a lookup with the month name, then use the month value to index the array to get the corresponding string.

Comment: Did you try `switch(month) { case 1: printf("January"); break; ... }`?

Comment: Ive tried using  switch(month) { case 1: printf("January"); break; ... }, but I didnt know how to make it work with the rest of my code. Do I just write the switch case for months first, and then just paste the rest of my code underneath it ? I know the questions I am asking are a bit moronic, but Im just starting to learn, so bear with me haha.

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner way than switch/if/else, create a lookup table to store the month names:

```
 static char * monthNames[12] = {"January","February",..etc..};
```

change the printf to use the month value as an index into the string array. Note that arrays are indexed starting at 0, so you have to decrement the month by one to get the correct index.

```
printf("The date entered is %d. %s %d. \n", day, monthNames[month-1], year);
```

Comment: I get that it is easier and way better to use arrays, but I still havent learned them. At the moment I am learning loops, and next week I will move forward to arrays.

Comment: @Mambaaa824 - Learning more is always better, but in this case, What you need to know to answer your question is all provided for you in the example in this answer.

Comment: I specifically said that at the moment I can only work with switch case and else/else if, so the code that he provided right now means nothing to me. Im grateful for the response,  but it doesnt help me atm.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the array approach, you can write a function that returns a pointer to the name of the correct month, using a `switch` statement/lookup table like you mentioned in your comment:

```
const char* getMonthName(int month)
{
  switch(month)
  {
    case 1: return "January";
    case 2: return "February";
    // ...
    case 12: return "December";
    default: return "Unknown";
  }
}
```

Then you can call it in `main`:

```
printf("The date entered is %d. %s %d. \n", day, getMonthName(month), year);
```

A few notes about this approach:

1. Each month name string defined in `getMonthName` is a *string literal*.  These are most often placed in read only memory of the executable, and you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you try to modify them.  Since I've made `getMonthName` return a `const char*`, You should at least get some support from the compiler in the form of a warning or error if you try to do something you shouldn't.  In general, be careful returning strings (more generally, arrays) from functions.  You cannot return local arrays from functions, as they go out of scope when the function returns, and the pointer that is returned now points to invalid data.  Since these string literals are *not* local to `getMonthName`, you're safe to return a pointer to them.
2. Some coding standards require one `return` statement per function.  I have yet to hear a good reason for that, but if that's your case, you can easily modify this to set a pointer to the appropriate string, then return that pointer.
3. This is clearly more code, but one advantage of this approach vs the raw array is this function has built-in bounds protection.  You already correctly check that `month` is within bounds, but that check will always need to accompany array access anywhere in your code.  In fact, best practice is to encapsulate bounds checking and month name retrieval in a function, no matter whether you use an array or a switch statement.  That way, you just have a single function call to get the month name and you can be assured even bogus inputs won't invoke UB.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array in this case array of pointers.

```
    printf("The date entered is %d. (%d)%s %d. \n", day, month, (char *[]){"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}[month], year);
```